# Export Office 365 SharePoint site list to excel 2016

Tags: office-365, excel

Trying to export office 365 SharePoint site list to **excel 2016**. following error occurs."**An unexpected error has occurred. Changes to your data cannot be saved"**

Any suggestions or solutions are appreciated.

Comment: How are you doing the exporting? If you are using browser, are you using IE?

Comment: yes I am using IE 11

Comment: Check your list's column names that they don't have any special characters (%, &, ...). Also reportedly people have had problems with spaces in the column names ("Column name" vs. "Column_name").

Comment: Do I have to change for example even (Created By to Created_By)

Comment: Just at first eliminate any special characters and test the behavior. I haven't experienced any issues with lists having the default "Created By"-column as it is, so that more likely concerns your custom columns.

Comment: I have tried both the above suggestions, I wonder if this error due to excel 2016? any help

Comment: There are many available suggestions for this, it's just up to you to find the one that fixes it. Try [1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c779151e-681b-4d5b-a43f-034c7f2b8bad), [2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b9713bbf-853b-4490-aeb1-1a50a7f26f46) and check whether you have any macros on your Excel sheet.

Comment: I have check all above suggestions, but the same error shows up again.

Comment: This seems to be an Excel 2016 bug. I've tested with the same site in Excel 2016 and Excel 2010. Those with Office 2010 can export without issue. It must have come through Office update, but now we need to find the update in question!

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue with SharePoint 2010 and Excel 2016 and I had to uninstall the 32-bit version of Office 2016, reboot, the install 64-bit version. It should then work. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem.  There are no special characters.  Here is the kicker.  If I export the query file ONLY from Edge Dev and ONLY From Edge dev it works